# Proving arbitrary set equality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

X,Y,Z are sets. Prove that $X-(Y\cap Z)= (X- Y)\cup (X- Z)$

So I know that I have to prove X - (Y ∩ Z) is a subset of (X - Y) ∪ (X - Z)
and also vice versa that (X - Y) ∪ (X - Z) is a subset of X - (Y ∩ Z).

So when I attempted the first, I clearly see how the logic works but I can't express it. Since the set is X - (Y ∩ Z) that means x ∈ X and x ∉ (Y ∩ Z).

For x ∉ (Y ∩ Z) by definition of intersection, x ∉ Y or x ∉ Z.

With that be stated can I just jump from x ∉ Y or x ∉ Z with x ∈ X to the conclusion that

(X - Y) ∪ (X - Z) ?

Comment: There is a useful acronym that mathematicians use a lot that I think will help you. WLOG means "without loss of generality". It is useful when you have an "or" statement in which either side is formally equivalent for the problem at hand. E.G. if we have $x\not\in Y$ or $x\not\in Z$, then I would say "assume WLOG that we have $x\not\in Y$ so then $x\in X-Y$." And I think you can finish. This is essentially a proof by cases where you say that two cases are all-but-identical. Be careful with this term though as if you use it when there is a loss of generality, it is VERY bad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Anwer 1.** $X-(Y\cap Z)=X\cap (Y\cap Z)^c=X\cap (Y^c\cup Z^c)=(X\cap Y^c)\cup (X\cap Z^c)=$$(X- Y)\cup (X- Z)$

> The second equality is by ["De Morgan's Law"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

---

**Anwer 2.** Let $a\in X-(Y\cap Z)$. So $(a\in X)\land (a\notin Y \lor a\notin Z)$. now by De Morgan's Law we have $(a\in X \land a\notin Y) \lor (a\in X \land a\notin Y).$ This means: $a\in (X- Y)\cup (X- Z)$.
The other side is similar. can you proceed?

Comment: $X-(Y\cap Z)=X\cap (Y\cap Z)^c$ what definition do you use to prove this? The set difference of X and (Y∩Z) is the intersection of X and the compliment of (Y∩Z)

Comment: [it is easy to see that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)): $A-B=A\cap B^c$

Comment: Yes thank you very much.

Comment: you are welcome.